# Add CAEmitterCell to another CAEmitterCell

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, caemitterlayer, caemittercell

I'm trying to do a particle effect where I have a cell nested onto another cell.  Think of the basic firework example they have here in the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAEmitterLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html).  They've nested Cells into other Cells and they've timed them using the BeginTime parameter.  I, however, do not have a "beginTime" parameter for my CAEmittorCell like they do, I have one in the CAEmittorLayer instead...  How am I supposed to nest cells and have them execute at different times if the cell does not have a beginTime parameter?

Notice in the apple example code they have a "beginTime" parameter for CAEmitterCell

```
**CAEmitterCell *firework = [CAEmitterCell emitterCell];**
firework.contents = img;
firework.birthRate = 9999;
firework.scale = 0.6;
firework.velocity = 130;
firework.lifetime = 2;
firework.alphaSpeed = -0.2;
firework.yAcceleration = -80;
**firework.beginTime = 1.5;**
firework.duration = 0.1;
firework.emissionRange = 2 * M_PI;
firework.scaleSpeed = -0.1;
firework.spin = 2;
```

---- Solved, see replies below ----

I simply called the selector manually like this to get the desired result:

```
CAEmitterCell cell = new CAEmitterCell();
cell.SetValueForKeyPath (NSNumber.FromFloat(1), (NSString)"beginTime");
```

Comment: @poupou Seems like `CAEmitterCell` conforms to the `CAMediaTiming` protocol in ObjC and the binding for it is missing in Xamarin.iOS. Then again `CAMediaTiming` seems to be missing completely!? https://github.com/mono/maccore/blob/master/src/coreanimation.cs#L48

Comment: Interesting, thanks for finding this.  Should I contact Xamarin support on this topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CAMediaTiming` bindings are not really missing. They were folded into `CAAnimation` ([here](https://github.com/mono/maccore/blob/master/src/coreanimation.cs#L801)) and `CALayer` ([here](https://github.com/mono/maccore/blob/master/src/coreanimation.cs#L380)). That's because, before 7.0's `[Protocol]` support, is was the way to implement protocols.

The issue is that `CAMediaTiming` is [documented](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAMediaTiming_protocol/Introduction/Introduction.html) to be adopted by only those two types - but `CAEmitterCell` (and maybe others, I need to check) also [conforms](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAEmitterCell_class/Reference/Reference.html) to it and *right now* do not expose the protocol methods.

The quick/immediate workaround is to call the missing selector on the instance. Future versions of Xamarin.iOS will provide them.

Comment: Excellent.  I never even thought of trying that.  Thanks!